# Perl calculator reads in numbers will not do calculation

Tags: perl

I have a problem with my simple calculator program. It is not performing the calculation with my `if` statement: it goes straight to the `else`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "enter a symbol operation symbol to and two numbers to make a calculation";

chomp($input = <>);

if ($input eq '+') {
  $c = $a + $b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq '-') {
  $c = $a - $b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq '*') {
  $c = $a * $b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq '/') {
  $c = $a / $b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq '%') {
  $c = $a % $b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq '**') {
  $c = $a**$b;
  print $c;
}
elsif ($input eq 'root') {
  $c = sqrt($a);
  $c = sqrt($b);
  print $c;
}
else {
  print " you messed up" . "$input" . "$a" . "$b";
}
```

Comment: Where are $a and $b assigned? Or should I post that as an answer?

Comment: could you post that as an answer with the code please

Comment: @JohnYost Ok how do I get it to take it on a single line

Comment: You have confused yourself with your indentation. Luckily the braces match and it compiles. I have tidied your code so that it is legible - please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

To start off with, you need to add [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) to the top of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

That is going to alert you to a lot of syntax errors, and force you to completely rethink/refactor your code.  This is a good thing though.

One obvious thing is that `$a` and `$b` are never initialized at all.  And your first `if` is missing the dollar sign before `input`.

I would change the capturing of your variables to the following:

```
print "enter a symbol operation symbol to and two numbers to make a calculation";

chomp(my $input = <>);

my ($operation, $x, $y) = split ' ', $input.
```

I'd also lean away from using `$a` and `$b` as variable names, as they are special variables used by perl's sort.  Once your certain that you're getting your input properly, then start working the rest of your logic.

Comment: so for the last section of code is that a initialization then a split into those variables using a space as a delimiter?

Comment: Yes, that is what I randomly chose as a delimiter.  It might make more sense to make the input ordered, so that `my ($x, $op, $y) = split ' ', $input`  However, regardless of what you choose, it's good to validate your data.  Ensure that each input is what you expect before moving on to the next section of code.  I realize you're new to perl though, so regular expressions probably aren't in your toolkit yet, but hopefully they will be eventually.

Comment: `split ' '` is special; it splits on any amount of whitespace and ignores leading whitespace (a good thing in this instance).  to split on just single spaces, you would do `split / /`

Comment: @Miller, I used your the delimiter section of code, I know a little java is there a way like string methods to grab that first character and continue on to an integer to compare it on this same line of input so I can compare or assign it to a variable?

Comment: Yes, there is [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) or using a regex for parsing.  Whatever, spec you come up with will be possible, the hardest part is just coming up with a clear spec.

Comment: *"lean away from"*? You should *never* use `$a` or `$b` as variable names as they are used directly by the Perl core. `$i` is fine; `$x`, `$y`and maybe `$z` are usually okay, and perhaps `$j` and `$k` if you *must* nest index variables. Indentifiers should be *concise and meaningful*.

Comment: @user3309169 Check to see if your divisor is 0 before attempting to divide.  If it is, throw out a [warning](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/warn.html) to the user and request new data.

Comment: @Miller I think I've got everything down but I can get my program to get out of a while pit what should I do

Comment: To exit a [while](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/while.html) loop, just use the [last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot '$' sign in the first condition before `input`:

```
if($input eq '+'){
$c = $a + $b;
print $c;
```

Comment: Ok that is fixed, but it is still not calculating based on the operation being read in.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $a = shift(@ARGV); // first argument is a
my $b = shift(@ARGV); // second argument is b
my $input = shift(@ARGV); // third argument is an operator
if($input eq '+'){...
```

Also, I would recommend 'use strict' and 'use warnings' at the top unless you're proficient at Perl.